# How can I tell if git was executed with the "-a" flag in a pre-commit hook?

Tags: git, githooks, git-commit, pre-commit-hook

I've got a git pre-commit hook which does linting. When it's invoked, it loops over the staged files and runs a linter on them. This works great.

However, when you run `git commit -am 'Foo'` it runs without having any staged files. How can I tell if it was invoked with `-a` or the `--all` flag? Is there an easier way to get the files which will be stored in git?

Comment: What you've described isn't the case. However you invoke `commit`, the pre-commit is executed with an index set to what's about to be committed and `HEAD` set appropriately so you can `git diff --cached --name-only` or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: I'm using `pygit2`. When I call `repo.status().items()` with unstaged files, I get something like this: `[('config/git_hooks/pre-commit', 256), ('bin/run_flake8', 256)]`. The `256` is the flag for GIT_STATUS_WT_MODIFIED.

Comment: I haven't looked at pygit2 (I wrote my own Python Git thing way back in the git 1.[567], python 2.[345] era, but that was several jobs ago and probably long discarded) but it's worth noting that `git status` does *two* diffs, one for index-vs-HEAD, and one for worktree-vs-index. Pygit2 may try to do the same thing, but if so it's getting it wrong, if you're doing this from within your pre-commit hook and running `git commit -a`.

Answer (score 1):

*All* the files in the index will be stored. You're looking for "files in the index that differ from their counterparts in `HEAD`", which you can find with `git diff`—or for scripts, `git diff-index`.

Note that the staged version may differ from the work-tree version as well, making checking everything especially annoying and tricky.  (For an example, run `git add -p` on some complex change, and select *part* of it.)

Here's an example of a dummy pre-commit hook that shows the name and status of each file with respect to `HEAD`, i.e., what's different in the index vs the existing `HEAD` commit.

```
#! /bin/sh

git diff-index --cached -r --name-status HEAD

echo pre-commit fail
exit 1
```

Your task is to take the output from `git diff-index --cached -r --name-status HEAD` (perhaps with `-z` added, perhaps not) and figure out how to test the versions that are in the index, not the versions that are in the work-tree.

Note that you can use `git checkout-index` to extract the index to a work-tree.  Of course, you'll want to avoid overwriting the *real* work tree, i.e., to establish a temporary work-tree elsewhere:

```
TMPTREE=$(mktemp -d)
...
git --work-tree=$TMPTREE checkout-index -- .
```

for instance.  You may want to establish a temporary index, other than the regular index, for this as well, since this may disturb the cache aspect of the regular index:

```
TMPINDEX=$(mktemp)
NORMINDEX=${GIT_INDEX_FILE:-$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/.index}
cp $NORMINDEX $TMPINDEX
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$TMPINDEX GIT_WORK_TREE=$TMPTREE checkout-index -- .
```

Be sure to clean up your temporary files and/or directories when done.

(None of these code fragments is tested.)